# Find the structure of very long JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am fairly new to using JSON form, but need a specific part of the parsed JSON for my project.  I was going to iterate through the proper object using dot notation.  However the JSON I am getting from the API is EXTREMELY long (almost 60 pages) and I do not want to have to go through and trace the structure of it.

Is there anyway to compress the structure or figure this out programmatically?

I am using Node js if that makes any difference in this instance.

Comment: Check out the API documentation.

Comment: `almost 60 pages` - meaningless measurement, if there's 2 lines per page, that's only 120 lines :p is it the readability that makes it hard for you to trace the structure?

Comment: Your editor is likely to have a JSON mode which will allow to collapse and expand different parts of the JSON structure. Or, there are on-line JSON viewers which allow the same thing. Or, you could consult the documentation for the API call, which will tell you the structure.

Comment: 60 pages isn't that much. Without a sample of the data or some code for what you've tried, this question is way too broad.

Comment: @Bergi This was a test harness for the API, so I didn't have the documentation sent with it.  Just contacted them and got the details.  Thanks!